# Wrapping a form with a <main> tag

Tags: forms, webforms

Should I wrap a web form into a  tag as follows? The form is the main content of my contact page. Or is not necessary?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Let’s keep in touch </title>
<!--CSS links, etc-->
</head>
<body>
<main>
<header><h1> Contact us </h1></header>
<form>
<!--Fieldset tags, legends, labels, Questions, text inputs, checkboxes, teaxtareas, submit button and so on-->
</form>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Or is just enough to use the `<fieldset>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) tag page on MDN:

> The `<main>` HTML element represents the dominant content of the `<body>` of a document. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document, or the central functionality of an application.

There are benefits to wrapping your main content (i.e., your form) in `<main>` tags, but don't feel obligated to do so. One particular benefit to wrapping your form and main content with `<main>` tags is [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#accessibility_concerns). However, there is nothing wrong with either case.